# SSL for local server

Tags: ajax, ssl, https, lan

How do I get an SSL certificate that works on my local network? It cannot be self-signed, as this messes up AJAX calls. I haven't found an issuer that would allow me to do something like this yet.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need a paid certificate for localhost.

You could make an self-signed and import it in browser certificate store. For ajax (and all other functionality) it will be absolutely correct one.

You could create such certificate with OpenSSL (command line tool) or with graphic tool as  [XCA](http://xca.sourceforge.net/) on Windows OS.

Comment: but ajax throws an error that it doesn't trust the self-signed certificate so it won't finish the request.

Comment: because you have not "imported it in browser certificate store"

Comment: ajax does not understand whether the certificate is self-signed, but it takes into account whether it is trustable or not. If you have certificate (non self-signed), which is signed by untrusted root, you suppose it would be trusted by ajax (but it won't). If you have self-signed certificate, which is trusted, ajax will accept it.